# Is the data behind the current osmnames.org built using latest OSM data and latest code in github.com/OSMNames/OSMNames?

Tags: openstreetmap

Performing fresh OSMNames extracts using latest codeset from https://github.com/OSMNames/OSMNames
often omits a level in the country/state/county/city hierarchy.

For example:
Vale of Glamorgan (in Wales, UK) is type:state_district and is defined in OSM (OSM id 103776, AdminLevel 6) as an admin boundary made up of ways and relations.
https://github.com/OSMNames/OSMNames/releases/download/v2.1.1/planet-latest_geonames.tsv.gz 2019 tsv file has Dinas Powys (OSM id 8219427, AdminLevel 10) as a town within Vale of Glamorgan.
As does the online https://osmnames.org/#q=Dinas%20Powys%2C

But an OSMNames build from latest 2021 data (https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/great-britain/wales-latest.osm.pbf) omits Vale of Glamorgan from Dinas Powys info.

If we try using older data in a Wales OSM history file - https://osm-internal.download.geofabrik.de/europe/great-britain/wales-internal.osh.pbf
Using osmium-tool to extract a data snapshot which should match the 2019 date of https://github.com/OSMNames/OSMNames/releases/download/v2.1.1/planet-latest_geonames.tsv.gz
(`osmium time-filter wales-internal.osh.pbf 2019-05-13T00:00:00Z -o wales_2019.osm.pbf`)
When we run the OSMNames build against this filtered file which should equal the May 2019 data, it still doesn't have Dinas Powys in Vale of Glamorgan.

So we appear to have a disparity between what was achieved in https://github.com/OSMNames/OSMNames/releases/download/v2.1.1/planet-latest_geonames.tsv.gz (generated in May 2019) and what we can reproduce using the https://github.com/OSMNames/OSMNames code
set.

Apparent conclusions:

- The current online `https://osmnames.org/#q=Dinas%20Powys%2C` is
  using OSMNames data from a few years ago, laid over current maptiles.
  If so, the website should make this clear.
- The `https://github.com/OSMNames/OSMNames/releases/download/v2.1.1/planet-latest_geonames.tsv.gz` was not built using unaltered code from the git repository.

The github site, states:
"If you are a user and have questions, we're sorry that we can't give individual support. Pls. ask support questions over at Stack Overflow", but there doesn't appear to be much activity.

Can anyone confirm my conclusions, or point me to something more recent?

As another example, the UK village of Fulletby:
In the 2019 tsv file, its display_name is "Fulletby, **East Lindsey**, Lincolnshire, **East Midlands**, England, United Kingdom".
But using latest codeset and OSM data gives a display_name of only "Fulletby, Lincolnshire, England, United Kingdom".